# Placing a label in specific corner of the chart

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, nodes

I plot two time series with `pgfplots` in one chart. I have a legend in the top right corner. Now, I would like to add a label (saying "Correlation = 0.86") in the top left corner. I have tried a lot with nodes, but I did not succeed in placing them in the top left corner. Is it possible to do that without using coordinates?

Comment: It would be ideal if you could provide the community with something to play with in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `rel axis cs` coordinate system to add nodes with labels `(rel axis cs:0,0)` is the lower left corner of the plot, and `(rel axis cs:1,1)` is the upper right corner of the plot. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,10)}; 
\node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {Correlation ${}= 0.86$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To add the label outside the axis you'll need `clip=false` as `axis` option.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to use `rel axis cs`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It might depend. I added a note about this in any case.

Comment: Well, if one is after the top left corner, then I think it makes more sense, as you don't have to think about what the limits on the axes are.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're absolutely right! I had a mental lapsus. Will update immediately. Thnaks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to give the `axis` environment a `name`, which you can refer to in the same way as other nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=theaxis]
%\node[below left] at (rel axis cs:1,1) {Correlation${}= 0.86$};
\end{axis}
\node [below right] at (theaxis.north west) {Correlation${}= 0.86$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```