# Add subfloat label (a) at the bottom left corner of a pgfplot figure

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats

I'm wondering what is the cleanest and simplest way to add a subfloat label (like (a)) at the bottom left of a `tikzpicture` or `pgfplot`. I generally export plots from matlab with `matlab2tikz` with this command `matlab2tikz('Figure_name.tikz', 'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth');`, but I don't mind manually editing the resulting file, as I anyhow need to make some cosmetic changes.

There are already some posts like [Reference pgfplots' groupplot with subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313713/reference-pgfplots-groupplot-with-subcaption) or [Placing a label in specific corner of the chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266770/placing-a-label-in-specific-corner-of-the-chart), but the location differs from what I would like to achieve.

Similarly, in [Put subfigure labels inside figures using subfig package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128844/put-subfigure-labels-inside-figures-using-subfig-package), there is a small macro defined to place the label exactly where I want if the code is modified into the following:

```
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\hspace*{5pt}\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{\sffamily\footnotesize{#2}}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spacing
}
```

When using a tikzpicture I modified the previous macro into

```
\newcommand{\modsubfigimg}[2][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{#1}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\hspace*{5pt}\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{\small{#2}}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spacing
}
```

but the result is not satisfactory visually.

Right now I'm using the following code snippet (with `\tikzexternalize`, but that's not relevant here), and the alignment inside each `minipage` is messed up (`\centering` can't be used for instance).

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\tikzsetnextfilename{PD-PWM_carrier_band}%
    \modsubfigimg[(a)]{\input{gfx/PDPWM_carrier_band.tikz}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\tikzsetnextfilename{PS-PWM_carrier_band}%
    \modsubfigimg[(b)]{\input{gfx/PSPWM_carrier_band.tikz}}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcounter{subfig}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfig}{\alph{subfig}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,10)}; 
\end{axis}
\node[below left] at (current bounding box.south west) {\stepcounter{subfig}(\thesubfig)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: It does well the job, if I modify `below left` to `above right` and move the `\stepcounter{subfig}` when using `\tikzexternalize`.